# TWAIN support for Google Chrome plugin

Tags: google-chrome, twain

Now, when Chrome states NPAPI [deprecated](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html) what are the alternatives for TWAIN scanning? It seems that NaCl does not have TWAIN support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative would be HTML5 + Web Socket. Dynamsoft (the company I work for) is looking at providing [such a solution](http://www.documentimagingreport.com/index.php?id=2533) for the customers using our NPAPI TWAIN Plugin.

Meanwhile, TWAIN Working Group is working on [SWORD](http://www.documentimagingreport.com/fileadmin/PDF_Content/2014/DIR_12-20-13-TWAIN-SWORD.pdf) for driverless scanning.

Comment: update: Dynamic Web TWAIN now provides a TWAIN HTML5 plugin to support non-NPAPI Chrome and Firefox. Here is the online demo you can try with: http://www.dynamsoft.com/demo/DWT/online_demo_scan.aspx

Comment: That is not Google chrome native way of using TWAIN, ISIS, SANE protocol. Please open request in Google Chrome issue trackker